# HOML excersice chapter 2 data augmentation in classification

Tags: python, machine-learning

problem quote

> Write a function that can shift an MNIST image in any direction (left, right, up, or down) by one pixel.⁠ Then, for each image in the training set, create four shifted copies (one per direction) and add them to the training set. Finally, train your best model on this expanded training set and measure its accuracy on the test set. You should observe that your model performs even better now! This technique of artificially growing the training set is called data augmentation or training set expansion.

my attempted solution:

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def shift_image(image, direction):
    image = image.reshape((28, 28))
    if direction == "right":
        return shift(image, [0, 1], cval=0)
    elif direction == "left":
        return shift(image, [0, -1], cval=0)
    elif direction == "up":
        return shift(image, [-1, 0], cval=0)
    elif direction == "down":
        return shift(image, [1, 0], cval=0)



shifted_images = []

for img in X_train:
    shifted_images.append(shift_image(img, "right"))
    shifted_images.append(shift_image(img, "left"))
    shifted_images.append(shift_image(img, "up"))
    shifted_images.append(shift_image(img, "down"))

# Convert the list of shifted images to a numpy array
X_train_shifted = np.array(shifted_images)
flattened_images = X_train_shifted.reshape((-1, 28 * 28))
print(flattened_images.shape)
print(X_train.shape)
X_combined = np.concatenate((X_train, flattened_images))
X_combined.shape



y_combined = np.concatenate((y_train,y_train,y_train,y_train,y_train))

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier()
sgd_clf.fit(X_combined,y_combined)
cross_val_score(sgd_clf,X_combined,y_combined,cv=3,scoring="accuracy")
```

cross val score output:

```
array([0.08093, 0.10234, 0.10207])
```

why am I getting a worse score than a dummy classifier?